AWS API Gateway CORS - CORS already setup at the API Gateway and in Lambda Function
I have added the domain that is making the request that is receiving the CORS message (a github.io page) into the CORS area of the API Gateway interface, but this doesn't help anything.

The front is calling the url with a js FETCH call, as a GET method. But CORS usually is server related, so it is something within the AWS API Gateway setting. Just bringing as much info as possible.
When I call the same url being called from my github page directly into the browser address bar the intended answer shows normally: "Hello from lambda!"

Anyone?
PS edit 1 (Thanks to Sergey K for bringing it up):
this API setting is simple HTTP:


Already tried the response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin with both Access-Control-Allow-Origin added into the API Gateway CORS showing at the first image.

Maybe: API Gateway > Integrations > Parameters Mapping  ?

I've already double checked the setup implementation to the called stage.

This question is similar to: Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Why content type is only authorization ? and what is your API Gateway configuration for CORS?

@jub0bs are you pretending you need to have access to some default "hello world" code to test something? There is no need to show the code in one way or another because it is only there for people who may reason that the problem may be related to these. But thank you for reminding that usually code images are far from optimal, anyway. Well noted, but it is not the case here. And the link you suggest is not related to AWS API Gateway. But thank you, anyway, for trying.

@GilkanSolizaris I'm not pretending anything. But you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Also, did you look up the other question I linked to in my earlier comment? Because, based on your first screenshot, it appears that what you've listed as allowed origins in your CORS configuration for API Gateway are in fact not valid Web-origin values.

In API Gateway you need to add a resource and Method with Options verb and make MOCK integration that always respond with 200 I have a piece of code in terraform where I configure the API gateway for CORS please check it and I hope it will helps to configure
   resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "cors" {
  rest_api_id = var.rest_api_id
  parent_id   = var.rest_api_parent_id
  path_part   = "{cors+}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "cors" {
  rest_api_id   = var.rest_api_id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.cors.id
  http_method   = "OPTIONS"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "cors" {
  rest_api_id = var.rest_api_id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.cors.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.cors.http_method
  type        = "MOCK"
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode(
      {
        statusCode = 200
      }
    )
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "cors" {
  depends_on  = [aws_api_gateway_method.cors]
  rest_api_id = var.rest_api_id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.cors.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.cors.http_method
  status_code = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true
  }
  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "cors" {
  depends_on  = [aws_api_gateway_integration.cors, aws_api_gateway_method_response.cors]
  rest_api_id = var.rest_api_id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.cors.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.cors.http_method
  status_code = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  = "'*'", # replace with hostname of frontend (CloudFront)
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET, POST, DELETE'" # remove or add HTTP methods as needed
  }
}


Isn't this setting related to REST resources? Forgot to mention my setting is simple HTTP request. I'll edit and add those infos, thanks.

@GilkanSolizaris yes it is to rest and worked for me fine. I can assume you can apply same integration for HTTP API as well
